# Can't get image to show up in swing

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I'm a college student and this is my first time I have ever created a gui in Java. Right now I looked at this answer [GUI in Java using Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837325/gui-in-java-using-swing) and followed the instructions and still nothing happens. Here is the code. I cut out all the irrelevant junk.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab4Shell 
{
    // this holds the current game board
        private char[][] gameBoard = new char[7][8];
        private JButton[][] gameButtons = new JButton[7][8];

        private ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("Red.jpg");
        private ImageIcon black = new ImageIcon("Black.jpg");
        private ImageIcon empty = new ImageIcon("Empty.jpg");

        private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        private int currentPlayer = 1;
        private int numMoves = 0;
        //Why do you want everything in constructor?
        public Lab4Shell()
        {
            CreateWindow();
            ResetGame();



            // set layout
            // loop through buttons array creating buttons, registering event handlers and adding buttons to panel
            // add panel to frame
            // do other initialization of applet
        }

        public static void CreateWindow()
        {
            //Sets window title and create window object.
            JFrame aWindow = new JFrame("Connect Four");
            //Set window position and size
            aWindow.setBounds(500,100,400,400);
            //What close button does.
            aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //Make window visible.
            aWindow.setVisible(true);


        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {

                    Lab4Shell game = new Lab4Shell();

                }
            });


        }
void ResetGame()
        {



            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(empty);
            for(int r=0;r<gameBoard.length;r++)
            {
                java.util.Arrays.fill(gameBoard[r],0,gameBoard[r].length,'0');



                //loop through board columns
                for(int c=0;c<gameBoard[r].length;c++)
                {

                }

            }
            // loop through array setting char array back to ' ' and buttons array back to empty pic
            // reset currentPlayer and numMoves variables
        }
```

Comment: Im using Eclipse and the image is in the program's bin folder.

Comment: For experimentation, you can use UI icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: @redelman431 :  Please have a look at how to [Add Images to your Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) for further clarification if you doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've never adding anything to your frame - which is causing your problem.  So in you `createWindow` method, you need to call:

```
aWindow.setContentPane(panel);
```

Then later on (like in your `resetGame` method), you'll add your content (like the `JLabel`) to the panel:

```
panel.add(empty);
```

Where it's added to your panel is determined by the [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) of the panel (there are many of them - the default is `BorderLayout`)

Other helpful things:

- Generally, when it makes sense, create/initialize your objects in the constructor and add/remove/update them in the runtime.
- For troubleshooting, use the `.setOpaque(true)` and `.setBackground(Color.blue)` methods on what you want to see.  If you don't see it then, either something is covering it up, or it was never added

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
add( picLabel );
```

Comment: +1 for the revised edition; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Comment: What class does add come from? My compiler does not like it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the created ImageIcons to the panel as Manos said, and being the images at the src folder of Eclipse project, do that:

```
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("red.JPEG");
ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: But what about that ImageSource instance variable up there? My professor wants me to use those. Should I put it in the constructor? But I'll give your idea a try

Comment: Yea man, give it a try and you see that it will work. You can put in the constructor, like this: ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/red.JPEG"));

Answer (score 2):

If the resources are embedded with the application (within in the jar), the you need to use `Class#getResource` to load them.

The preferred mechanism for loading images is through the [`ImageIO` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html).  It supports more image formats (as well as providing a pluggable architecture) and guarantees an image that is ready to be displayed once the `read` method returns

```
BufferedImage redImage;

// ... 

URL url = getClass().getResource("red.JPEG");
if (url != null) {
    redImage = ImageIO.read(url);
} else {
    throw new NullPointerException("Unable to locate red image resource");
}
```